# Как создать список/словарь из датафреймов, полученных из xlsx файлов в python?

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe, словари

У меня есть 3 файла excel (.xls). Я хочу создать список или словарь, которые содержали бы дата фреймы, полученные из этих файлов.
Я использую код:

```
all_datasets = {years:pd.read_excel(download_dir+'\index'+str(year)+'_data.xls') for year in years}
display(all_datasets[2017])
```

где years - список годов, за которые у меня собраны данные (2017, 2018, 2019), а download_dir - директория, где эти файлы хранятся.
Когда я пытаюсь вывести словарь целиком или его часть по ключу, я получаю пустой словарь/просто ничего

То же самое со списками. Для них я использую код:

```
all_datasets = [pd.read_excel(download_dir+f'\index'+str(year)+'_data.xls') for year in years]
```

Название файлов одинаковое, меняется только год

Comment: `+'/index'+str(year)+` или `+'\\index'+str(year)+` или `+r'\index'+str(year)+`

Comment: за эту поправку спасибо, не заметила, но дело кажется не в этом

Comment: остальное без данных трудно подсказать. посмотрите для начала каждый загруженный фрейм

Answer (score 0):

Всем привет! Спасибо, кто ответил.
Проблема была в списке years. Нужно было создавать его либо прямо перед этой строчкой (до этого он создавался где-то в начале кода), либо вместо years прямо использовать список [2017, 2018, 2019], не создавая перед этим. То есть либо:

```
years = [2017, 2018, 2019]
all_datasets = {years:pd.read_excel(download_dir+'\index'+str(year)+'_data.xls') for year in years}
```

Либо:

```
all_datasets = {years:pd.read_excel(download_dir+'\index'+str(year)+'_data.xls') for year in [2017, 2018, 2019]}
```

В моем конкретном случае формат строки роли не играл, однако на это тоже обращайте внимание (спасибо первому ответу)